# Programatically adding and modifying command buttons (active X control) - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello this have been giving me a headache for a while.

I want to simply be able to remove existing buttons and add new ones. I already have ready made functions xbutton_click() and ybutton_click(). I tried adding buttons like this:

```
Set btn= ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Range("B3").Left, Range("B3").Top, Range("B3").Width, Range("B3").Height)
With openForm
    .OnAction = "new_Click"
    .Caption = "new"
    .Name = "newButton"
End With
```

but those seem to only work with macros which is **not** what I want. I realized that when I manually add a button, I add the active X control button. **I want that**. It has a name property, which can be changed, and its function is basically name_click(), perfect!

Now when it comes to adding them its a headache. I have surfed the internet but it is full of outdated solutions (I am using 2013). I could only add new command buttons, but couldn't change their caption, name, nothing.

this is the code for adding a "command button" (not "button"):

```
Set objBtn = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", link:=False, _
    displayasicon:=False, Left:=celLeft, Top:=celTop, Width:=celWidth, Height:=celHeight)
```

Adding the ActiveX Command Button works, but I cannot change its properties like "Caption". Can someone please guide me through this maze?

**Edit**

objBtn.Name = "newName" works. But objBtn.Caption = "newCaption" gives an error 438.

Comment: Form controls can be assigned any given macro. Therefore, you have the option with them to assign a macro to them upon creation using the `.OnAction`. Yet, ActiveX controls do not come with this option. The macro (when clicking on `CommandButton1` for example) must be named `CommandButton1_Click` and must reside on the sheet where the ActiveX command button resides. So, what you are essentially asking for is a macro (VBA code) to change the VBA code residing on a particular sheet.

Comment: Sorry, what is it you want, to add ActiveX buttons or a form button.  The ActiveX code is listed above

Comment: There are solutions out there to change the VBA code (with VBA code) for a module in a particular Excel file. Yet, I have not yet come across a solution to change the VBA code on a worksheet using VBA code. Maybe someone here has a solution for that one.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav himura specifically wrote in his/her title that he/she wants to add an ActiveX control (not a form control). So, he/she will have to change the VBA code on the underlying sheet in order to make the button work.

Comment: @Ralph, thanks for that, that was my confusion.

Comment: You should be able to use `objBtn.Name = "newButton"` to set the name of your ActiveX Command Button after it is created. This has worked for me in 2010 and 2016 without issue

Comment: @Ralph this is exactly what I said. What I want is in the title ( I will make the question clearer) I want to deal with ActiveX Command Buttons, not the button control with macros. Also I have tried the solution of changing the VBA code on a worksheet using VBA code with no success. I got an error about insecure access to VBProject. The post I got the code from was over 6 years old. Also just to clarify, I do not want to change the VBA code. I just want to change the newly created command button's caption and other properties

Comment: Once again, in this case (to make the button do something when it is clicked) you'll need to have a VBA `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` on your worksheet to make the button work. As suggested by @JerryT you could have already such a sub on your sheet and then name the new button accordingly to (automatically) associate the button with this sub. As commented above: the name of the sub **has to be** the same name as the button for ActiveX buttons.

Comment: yes I have the Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(). It is already there. Also, the .name property worked. However, I want also to change the caption of the button and I get run-time error 438.

Comment: I have Edited the question

Comment: In order to change the caption you need to use `objBtn.Object.Caption = ""` You can find this by adding a 'watch' on your command button and looking at the hierarchy of properties

Comment: Thanks @JerryT so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OLEObjects, you can't do it just a caption this should solve it

```
Dim objBtn As OLEObject
Set objBtn = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    objBtn.Object.Caption = "Example"
```

Notice you were missing `.Object.`
[image]